# Open a ajaxmodalpopup from a hyperlink

Tags: c#, asp.net

, I would like to know how i can trigger a modal pop up when clicking a hyperlink, basically i have seen a lot of example using a button like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" /> 
    <ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="Button1_ModalPopupExtender" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" 
        Enabled="True" TargetControlID="Button1" PopupControlID="Panel1" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"> 
    </ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender>
```

But how about if instead of a button its a hyperlink, which is an image... how can i triger the modal pop up to open when the hyperlink is clicked?

Here is my hyperlink

```
<asp:HyperLink id="imageHyperLink" runat="server"  Target="_parent"
                        ImageUrl='some url'
                        NavigateUrl='some url'
                        ToolTip = 'some tool tip'
                        Visible='true' />
```

So when i click on the image, i would like to open the pop up.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the ModalPopupExtender's TargetControlID to the hyperlink's id.